# ipython fails to start

Tags: python, ipython

I had previously installed ipython against python2.7.
After I installed `python3-pip` using

```
$sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

and ran the following command

```
$sudo pip3 install ipython
```

, I'm unable to start `ipython`.
I get the following errors:

```
kv@kv:~$ ipython


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 7, in <module>
    from IPython import start_ipython
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from .config.loader import Config
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/loader.py", line 165
    except KeyError, e:
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 20, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt_pkg.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 7, in <module>
    from IPython import start_ipython
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from .config.loader import Config
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/loader.py", line 165
    except KeyError, e:
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I make `ipython` work under both `python2.7` and `python3.4`

Updated :

```
kv@kv:~$ ipython2
No command 'ipython2' found, did you mean:
 Command 'python2' from package 'python-minimal' (main)
 Command 'ipython' from package 'ipython' (universe)
 Command 'ipython3' from package 'ipython3' (universe)
ipython2: command not found
```

and for   `kv@kv:~$ ipython3`
I get the error mentioned earlier

Comment: have you considered using two separate virtual environments?

Comment: @JohnTitusJungao yes, invoking ipython doesn't work in either of them and produces the same error

Comment: You seem to be running python 2 code in python 3

Comment: @ppperry No, I just invoked ipython which was installed against python2.7

Comment: The reason I made that comment is that the line that the syntax error is complaining about is syntactically valid python 2 code.

Comment: Try running ipython2.7 and it should work.

Comment: @NipunTalukdar Yes, that works! and it shows for python2.7, what about for python3?

Comment: @kvmanohar As you see "except KeyError, e:" is not a valid Python3 syntax and hence it is resulting in the error. Also, ipython3 still seems using Python 2.7 modules (as it is importing modules from /usr/lib/python2.7 ). Have you set environment variable PYTHONPATH explicitly?

Comment: @NipunTalukdar Yes, I have set it and here is the output.
 kv@kv:~$ echo $PYTHONPATH 
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages

Comment: @kvmanohar I guess this is the problem. As PYTHONPATH is pointing to   /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages first. Please try un-setting PYTHONPATH and check.

Comment: Consider installing ipython via apt-get instead of pip. Installing applications via a package mananger is generally more advisable (i.e. more likely to work) than other means.

Answer (score 0):

For me below commands works to shift b/w python versions.

To start ipyton for python 2

```
$ ipython2
```

To start ipython for python 3

```
$ ipython3
```

Comment: try `$ python -m  IPython`